# Are there systematic ways to tune the Kalman filter in engineering practice?

Tags: kalman-filter

Including Q, R, and initial states of x and P.

Comment: The body of this question isn't even a complete sentence.  Can you add some more background about what behavior you are trying to get from the system?  In what way is it out of tune now, and what measurements do you have access to?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you are asking for ways to set initial x(the state vector),  initial P (the covariance matrix), the process noise covariance matrix Q and the measurement noise covariance matrix R. For the first two you have to use common sense and any knowledge you have. If you are estimating the position and velocity of a moving vehicle lets say then they should be the initial position of the vehicle and perhaps 0 if you start from stationary. The P matrix can also be calculated based on the uncertainty you have about these initial positions. But you don't have to worry too much about these because they will converge. The R matrix is usually taken from the spec sheet of your sensors and contains the accuracy(variance) of the sensor. This tutorial will help with the estimate of the Q matrix [http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~ian/Teaching/Estimation/LectureNotes2.pdf](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Eian/Teaching/Estimation/LectureNotes2.pdf). Finally there is a good way to verify if your estimate of Q is good. Just look at the innovation(z-Hx_pred) and innovation covariance matrix. If the innovation for the states is not within 2 std.devs (as taken from the innovation covariance matrix) then you are underestimating the noise.

Comment: *"But you don't have to worry too much about these because they will converge."* careless statement. If you think your kalman filter will converenge from the first attempt, you are ostensibly mistaken. There is a plethora of pitfalls need to be avoided for the KF to work properly.

Comment: &CroCo, OP is requesting a systematic approach for the problem. Are you able to refine your comment into an additional answer - - - what are the plethora of pitfalls?